# How to put data on listView,passed by another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

This is my second class.What i want is to put that "choice" on listView

```
    listViewDesc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDesc);
    listViewPrice = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPrice);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String choice = null;
    if(extras != null)

    choice = extras.getString("name");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), choice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: there is some data which is passed from another class to this class..to check whether the data is actually passing i put the Toast and it is correctly executing. now i want to put that data on listView not on Toast. help me out in this

Comment: what I meant is what did you try so far in order to accomplish your goal of putting the data into the ListView?

Comment: this is all what i got, I've go through different examples but dint found any thing related to my qestion

Comment: you just want to display a `String` passed via an `Intent` into a `ListView`?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following tutorial, this is a simple listview example. You already have your string, so put it in how he shows.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html

```
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", choice));
```